# Jenkins downstream error not propagated to upstream

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline to build which will trigger another pipeline for running the (long) tests. My idea is to have the downstream test job run without waiting (to allow frequent build jobs). However, when I add `wait: false` to the build job command a failure will not change the status of the build job:

JenkinsfileBuild

```
node {

    def app

    stage('Clone repository') {
    }

    stage('Merge main') {
    }

    stage('Build image') {
    }

    stage('Upload image') {

        sh "echo would push image here"
    }

}

stage('Test Image') {
    build job: "../${env.JOB_NAME.split("/")[0]}Test/${env.BRANCH_NAME}", wait: false 
}
```

JenkinsfileTest

```
node {

    stage('Run Test') {
        sh "exit -1";
    }

}
```

I was expecting that the failing test job would mark the build job as failed as it does, when wait: true is set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `propagate: true` option to the build step. And you need to wait for the Job in order to get the result.

```
build job: "../${env.JOB_NAME.split("/")[0]}Test/${env.BRANCH_NAME}", wait: true, propagate: true
```

---

If you don't want to wait for the Job you can execute things in [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel).

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Your Stages") {
            parallel {
                stage("Buld Job") {
                    build job: "../${env.JOB_NAME.split("/")[0]}Test/${env.BRANCH_NAME}", wait: true, propagate: true
                }
                stage("Other Stuff") {
                      sh(‘cd /path/to/proj-2 && make && make publish’)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we want to avoid waiting in order to build more rapidly. Is there any property the test job could set on the build job after completion?

Comment: @DaSteph What you need is parallel execution, check the update in the answer.