# pass value from job2 to job1 jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins `job1` which triggers `job2`

```
stage("trigger job2") {
       steps {
           build job: job2,
                parameters: [
                    string(name: "test1", value: "test1"),
                    string(name: "test2", value: "test2"),
                ],
```

and `job2` triggered and running, I need to know if `job2`'s last stage fails; for example, in my case, the last stage is "RESULT". Now, if the RESULT stage on `job2` is red/failed, return this one pass to `job1` and in `job1` stage trigger `job2` should also display in red.

I tried these cases but they do not work.

Jenkins version is Jenkins 2.346.1

What I tried:

JOB1: modified

```
 def p = build job: job2, propagate: true,
                parameters: [
                    string(name: "test1", value: "test1"),
                    string(name: "test2", value: "test2"),
                ],
            script {
                    build.waitForCompletion()
            }
            if (p.result == 'FAILURE') {
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                error 'Job2 failed, marking Job1 as failed in the current stage'
                }
            }
```

Try 2:

JOB1 modified

```
def result = build.waitForCompletion()
            if (result.result == 'FAILURE') {
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                error 'Job2 failed, marking Job1 as failed in the current stage'
            }
```

I tried 3-4 different cases, but they didn't work, could someone advise me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins downstream error not propagated to upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74657976/jenkins-downstream-error-not-propagated-to-upstream) (basic result propagation to an upstream job).   
If more complex data passing is needed, there's another question & answers also related to both result(s) and parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539613/return-parameters-results-from-a-jobtriggered-by-pipeline-back-to-the-same-pip

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the default behaviour in Jenkins.
Jenkins job fails be default if any of its stages fail. Job2 will fail if its last stage fails. As far as I know and what [doc says](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) it is enough to write this:

```
build job: job2,
            parameters: [
                string(name: "test1", value: "test1"),
                string(name: "test2", value: "test2"),
            ]
```

to make job1 fail when job2 fails. Stage which triggers job2 (in job1) should be red as you want.